# How to change graphic quality using AS3 , giving users an option button?

Tags: actionscript-3

If I want to change the graphic quality display of the swf file by right click and click quality.

Is there a type of code to apply this in-game when a button is pressed?

If there is, please help! Thanks!

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/StageQuality.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change quality of stage, for low:

```
stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
```

for medium, change `LOW` to `MEDIUM`

for high, change `LOW` to `HIGH`

for best, change `LOW` to `BEST`

Function to do it:

```
function best(event: MouseEvent): void {
  stage.quality = StageQuality.BEST;
}

best_qual_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, best);
```